# "npm publish" throwing "Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters"

Tags: npm-publish

I have a rather large package (1.3Gb which is unfortunately, for now, outside of my control). We need to publish it to artifactory in order to continue with a POC before we break it up into smaller pieces.

Whenever I run `npm publish` I am being hit with the following error:

```
44 timing command:publish Completed in 55913ms
45 verbose stack Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
45 verbose stack     at Object.slice (node:buffer:643:37)
45 verbose stack     at Buffer.toString (node:buffer:812:14)
45 verbose stack     at buildMetadata (/Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmpublish/lib/publish.js:130:23)
45 verbose stack     at publish (/Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmpublish/lib/publish.js:40:20)
45 verbose stack     at /Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/publish.js:120:46
45 verbose stack     at otplease (/Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/otplease.js:4:18)
45 verbose stack     at Publish.exec (/Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/publish.js:120:13)
45 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/Users/gmcgrath/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
46 verbose cwd /Users/gmcgrath/Downloads/gmcgrath/test-content
```

Unfortunately I can't find much information about max size that can be published. Wether it's an issue on the npm side, artifactory side or elsewhere.

Has anyone ran into the above issue before when trying to publish a large package? If so, is there a potential workaround for this for now?